# blank "DOMNodeList" reading XML via Xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am trying to read the value of "SIM" via the below PHP code via the XML given below, but for some reason it gives me a blank "DOMNodeList" Any idea what i am doing wrong here ? I wanted to set that element as

```
<ns1:SIM old="8902"> 000000 </SIM>
```

How do i do that, because I am trying with below code to find it but it seems output is "DOMNodeList" empty.

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('ns1', 'http://www.example.com/WSG/ec/');
$result = $xpath->query("/ns1:ModifySIMRequest/ns1:ServiceProfile/ns1:Primary/ns1:SIM");
        foreach ($result AS $node) {
            var_dump($node);
            echo $node->nodeValue;
        }
```

XML in $doc is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns1:ModifySIMRequest xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/WSG/ec/">
  <ns1:ServiceProfile>
    <ns1:Speech>
      <ns1:MSN>33808089</ns1:MSN>
      <ns1:AccountNumber>8989895</ns1:AccountNumber>
    </ns1:Speech>
    <ns1:Primary action="mod">
      <ns1:BillingOption>dsdsd</ns1:BillingOption>
      <ns1:SIM old="8902"/>
    </ns1:Primary>
  </ns1:ServiceProfile>
</ns1:ModifySIMRequest>
```

Comment: what do you mean empty? [there it is](https://eval.in/900934), but of course no text content just an attribute, just like the above

Comment: @Ghost how do i read that attribute and set it as above ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#95545

Comment: issue is it doesnt even goto the foreach ($result AS $node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get attribute

```
        echo $node->getAttribute('old');  // 8902
```

To set value

```
        $node->nodeValue = '000000';
        echo $doc->saveXML(); // <ns1:SIM old="8902">000000</ns1:SIM>
```

Comment: Doest get into the for loop for some reason

Comment: Echo $node-value is never executed

Comment: The element you find - `<ns1:SIM old="8902"/>` has no value

Comment: @mahen3d Maybe, you don't know that shash at the end of element mean the  reduction of `<el /> => <el></el>`-  with empty value

Comment: i figured it out issue was that i didnt called $doc->loadXML function explicitly i thought it was able detect the XML by default. you sample code help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Perfect! :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The text content/node value of the element `{http://www.example.com/WSG/ec/}SIM` is empty. If you want to fetch the attribute here are two ways. You can use DOM methods to read the attribute values or extend the Xpath expression to fetch the attribute node. If you fetch the attribute you can even cast it into a string in the Xpath expression directly.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('ec', 'http://www.example.com/WSG/ec/');

$result = $xpath->evaluate("/ec:ModifySIMRequest/ec:ServiceProfile/ec:Primary/ec:SIM");
foreach ($result AS $node) {
  // use the DOM method to fetch the attribute
  var_dump($node->getAttribute('old'));
}

// fetch the attribute node using Xpath
$result = $xpath->evaluate("/ec:ModifySIMRequest/ec:ServiceProfile/ec:Primary/ec:SIM/@old");
foreach ($result AS $node) {
  var_dump($node->textContent);
}

var_dump(
  // fetch the value of the first matching attribute as a string
  $xpath->evaluate("string(/ec:ModifySIMRequest/ec:ServiceProfile/ec:Primary/ec:SIM/@old)")
);
```

Note: The namespace alias/prefix does not need to match the alias in the document. You can use a more meaningful one.